# Merger of Multiple matrices using Matlab/Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, overlapping

Assuming we have 3 matrices, `A`, `B` and `C`, all are of the same size `256x256`. It is known that last 20% of columns of Matrix `A` is identical to first 20% of Matrix `B` and last 10% of Matrix `B` is identical to first 10% of Matrix `C`. So in these cases since we know the overlapping amount, I do not need to compare the 3 matrices, but i want to join them at the overlap.

Taking a smaller Matrix as an example here are the 3 Matrices

```
A = [1 2 3 4 ; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12];
B = [3 4 13 14; 7 8 15 16; 11 12 17 18]; 
C = [14 19 20 21; 16 22 23 24; 18 25 26 27];
```

So I would like my output to be

```
D = [1     2     3     4    13    14    19    20    21
     5     6     7     8    15    16    22    23    24
     9    10    11    12    17    18    25    26    27
```

I hope this might explain it better. I am extremely new to matlab. I tried using matrix shift, but we have only circular shift available.
Concatenation does not work because it just joins the 3 matrices. What would be the best way to overlay these 3 matrices together ?

Comment: can you provide what you got so far?

Comment: How do you want to marge this 3 matrix? this is not so clear: do you want to marge them to have a 3D matrix? one layer for each matrix? Explain please and try to provide a piece of code to understand

Comment: or create an example with three 4x4 matrices and the desired output

Comment: @Moorthi please consider to edit your question to add information concerning your problem

Comment: assuming you always know the amount of overlap, then this is simply an indexing issue as pointed out below by serial. if you want concatenation with unknown degree of overlap it can gets much more involved depending on desired level of efficiency.

Comment: If indexing is your stumbling block, I suggest working through the following Matlab documentation page, playing with the examples as you go
https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#

Comment: Currently I think Indexing will work. But once I have more data and data points then I think I could narrow it down to other possible solutions. But if the data I receive is tricky, then I might get false positives if I go with finding common columns within the matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make proper use of matrix [indexing](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) and [concatenation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85019)

For your example

```
D = [A B(:,3) C];
```

For a `256x256` Matrix and your concatenation conditions:

```
D = [A B(:, 0.2*256+1 : 0.9*256) C]
```

Since `256/10` is no integer you may adjust the index values